# Made a commit, now master has 0 parents

Tags: git

A colleague made a commit to `master` that somehow is separate from all history. Github shows `0 parents` when viewing the commit. I don't know what the last "good" commit to `master` was, it was probably a merge from a feature branch. Where do I even start fixing this?

Comment: Semi-serious answer: http://xkcd.com/1597/

Comment: Not entirely helpful, but it does seem to explain how this issue occurred. :)

Comment: I assume that this collegue pushed with `git push -f` (because the git server would have rejected the push). Thus you should `git push -f` a correct commit.

Comment: You can use `git reflog` to see the entire history of your repo. You can `checkout` any of the revisions and then `merge` in whatever you need

Comment: You also might want to consider looking at your repo with a visual client like SourceTree - that can give you a better picture of the state of your repo.

Comment: Also, consider that github now offers the possibility to protect a branch against force-pushes: https://github.com/blog/2051-protected-branches-and-required-status-checks

Comment: @wil93 doing this now. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Your colleague most likely managed to create a commit without history somehow, then pushed it to github. I wouldn't expect github to normally accept such a push, though, since it rewrites history -- maybe your colleague used the `--force` option.

Anyways, the first thing to do when you lose a commit in git is always `git reflog`. It will show you a log of what commits you have had as HEAD lately, and you can check them out using the commit's SHA1 id.

So, if you find a good commit with SHA1 "abcdef", you can `git checkout abcdef` and take a look at the contents. If you want to make that your master branch, do `git checkout abcdef -b master` (replace `-b` with `-B` to overwrite your existing master branch).

These are all local operations, though. To get it up on github, you of course have to `git push` it. However, since your colleague has rewritten history, you'll have to *repeat* your colleague's mistake: you'll have to `git push --force`.

Comment: You can look at a commit without checking it out: `git log -1 <sha-1>`, `git show <sha-1>`, and so on.  This is mostly useful for quickly excluding lots of candidates (if you have lots) so that you get down to a few you can examine closely by checking them out.

Comment: Will this fix the network graph? I want a fix that restores the commit parent/child relationships. Would it be easier to delete my colleague's commit entirely?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "network graph"? The complete git history? Then yes, because a commit is defined not only by its contents, but also its ancestors. So if you `git push --force` a suitable commit, you will upload that commit and all of its history, replacing whatever commits and history are on github.